# C++ vs C for distributed computing

Tags: c++, c, mpi, distributed-computing

I am about to start a new project in scientific computing, which will run on a computer cluster using from 8 up to 32 CPUs. I will use MPI to distribute the calculations. The last thing is which language is better to use C or C++? I will do some serious number crunching, and I will need a smooth and well-distributed parallelization. I have no experience using MPI, but I am aware that it suits C much more than C++, even if libraries like boost::MPI are used. Taking into account that performance is crucial, what language is better to use?

**Note:** Of course, one could write C-style code on C++, but that wouldn't be C++ after all. When I speak of C++ I mean to use lots of OOP and generic programming.

Comment: OOP should be a means to a goal, not a goal in itself.  Not unless you just want to learn how to do OOP.

Comment: there is no good reason not to use C++.  boost::mpi is very nice and lets you do things easily.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can write slow code in any language.  MPI is a *message-passing library* so it simply does not care whether you call it from C or C++ --- use whichever language *you* are better at.

Which you should determine by profiling and measuring.

The [Language Shootout comparison between C and C++](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/c.php) is pretty even about size, speed and memory use.

Lastly, there is also the underestimated importance of 'time to code'. You may get to a *working program* faster in C++ than in C simply because you have more high-level tools at your disposal.  Or you may not, so I would try to measure.

Comment: +1 for measuring. People shouldn't claim "C++ is faster than C" or "C is faster than C++" or "Boost is faster than a ferrari" or "Jon Skeet is faster than light" or whatever. It depends wholly on how you're using them. Measure, please.

Comment: Gah. I can’t stand the Alioth language shootout. It’s absolutely misleading because it merely shows that you can write Assembly in any languge. It’d doesn’t show at all how fast *typical code* in any given language is and how such languages *support* efficient programming. In judging that, the shootout is flat out useless.

Comment: Konrad, good points, but *empirics* still rule even when subject to valid criticism.  I fear that what you suggest would lead to rejection of all comparisons *just because things are incomparable*.  No?

Comment: @Dirk Not at all. But I agree that real comparisons are much harder than the simplistic Alioth shootout makes them out to be. I’m all for empiricism and I actually like the original idea of the Alioth shootout but I think it has completely failed in practice. Better tests are unfortunately very rare but I never tire of referring to [a study by Lutz Prechelt](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/prechelt/Biblio/jccpprt_computer2000.pdf) which in my opinion has the best test layout to determine such distionctions in a fair way.

Comment: @Konrad,  I glanced at the paper: it comes back to 'time to code / size', 'speed' and 'memory use' as metrics. Hm, just the Alioth Shootout. See a pattern? ;-) But I am with you on criticism of the submitted codes.  Maybe one should come up with a wikified, crowdsourced alternative.  Feels like there are few more Software Engineering papers or dissertations left.

Comment: @Dirk The paper importantly also measures code complexity and time taken to develop the solution. Furthermore, the focus here was explicitly on using the language facilities well to solve the problem, not on solving the problem most efficiently at all cost. Which is what happens in the Alioth shootout. For example, nobody in their right mind would use SIMD primitives in real code, except in very rare cases.

Comment: @Konrad: But how on earth does one impose that constraint in a *competitive* comparison? *Give us your codes, but make them very average.* Does not strike me as operational, and we're back to my criticism of your criticism (calling incomparable) of earlier.

Comment: @Dirk & @Konrad - It's been nearly 4 years since the project name changed. If you can't even get the name right...

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph - How exactly do you know what is "typical" code? How do you know that your idea of "typical" is not parochial?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph >>I never tire of referring to a study by Lutz Prechelt<< A study which throws together 2 different data sets - Java, C, and C++ programs from a controlled experiment; and Perl, Python, Rexx, and Tcl programs from a diverse range self selected authors - and then simply guesses that difference doesn't make a large difference to the measurements.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph >>The paper importantly also measures code complexity and time taken to develop the solution.<< 1) No. It reports program length LoC not complexity - the benchmarks game also provides a measure of program size. 2) No. It only measures time taken to develop for Java, C, and C++ programs - the time taken for Perl, Python, Rexx, and Tcl programs was self-reported by the program authors.

Comment: @igouy “If you can't even get the name right” – I was almost certain that someone would make that point. Let me spell it out: your point is stupid, doesn’t pertain to the argument, and you drag the level of the discussion down by making it. In case you haven’t noticed: space in the comments is very limited and I deliberately chose a concise name in favour of the “correct”, convoluted one.

Comment: @igouy Pertaining to the Prechelt study: again, comment space is limited. I usually mention that the study was merely preliminary, that the idea is right but that much more needs to be done to get reliable results but that ultimately *this* is the only kind of study that has any validity. Any of these explanations you could have found by a cursory perusal of the study and the follow-up research done by Lutz Prechelt’s group. Your criticisms of the study *are* justified but the authors are aware of that and act accordingly.

Comment: @Konrad >>a concise name<< alioth shootout = 15 benchmarks game = 15

Comment: @Konrad >>I usually mention that the study was merely preliminary<< You didn't this time and if as you say the paper you linked to was preliminary (published 2000) please provide a link to the final study.

Comment: @igouy “benchmark game” = official name? News to me but then again you seem closer affiliated to it than I am so you should know. – I never mentioned a “final study”. There’s no such thing (it also smacks of oxymoron). Furthermore, even though this was preliminary, I didn’t say its results cannot be used. They *can* (and the paper explicitly addresses this). That said, follow-ups can be found here: http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/prechelt/Biblio/ (esp. Plat_Forms). Unfortunately, I know of no other such work, probably because the research is underfunded and the evaluation is a lot of work.

Comment: @igouy In reply to other commends you made: “1) No. It reports program length LoC not complexity” … which is a measure of complexity, albeit an unsophisticated one. But I agree that this should be improved. | “2) …” – the paper *does* address why the self-reported times are roughly reliable, and gives evidence for that claim. | “How exactly do you know what is "typical" code?” Arguably only by analyzing real projects, not ones written in artificial conditions. Real conditions can be approximated though. But pure performance benchmarks systematically *destroy* those conditions.

Comment: @Konrad >>“benchmark game” = official name? News to me<< A concise abbreviation of the official name, and enough for Google http://www.google.com/search?q=benchmarks+game Nearly 4 years since the project name changed and it's news to you?

Comment: @Konrad 1) >>which is a measure of complexity, albeit an unsophisticated one<< On that basis, the benchmarks game shows a somewhat more sophisticated "measure of complexity" 2) >>why the self-reported times are roughly reliable, and gives evidence for that claim<< The study appeals to "common software engineering wisdom"! 3) So you don't actually know what is "typical" code?

Comment: @igouy Can you please refrain from muddying the discussion with irrelevant side-issues? It is super annoying. Furthermore, http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=alioth. | 1) where? You previously said that it also (merely) provided SLOC. 2) What’s wrong with that? This common wisdom is plausible and well supported by numbers (in particular, it is supported by the numbers in the paper). | 3) I do. I have explained that. What do you want from me? To give you a generative grammar of typical code?

Comment: @Konrad >>Furthermore, http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=alioth<< "Free project hosting especially for software to do with Debian."

Comment: @Konrad >>You previously said that it also (merely) provided SLOC.<< No - quote my exact words. I said "the benchmarks game also provides a measure of program size". And this takes us back to "If you can't even get the name right..." as an indicator that someone may have misread or misunderstood or simply not looked for years and years and years.

Comment: @Konrad - >>3)So you don't actually know what is "typical" code?<< All you've done is suggested someone would need to analyze real projects - you haven't suggested what it is about the code in those real projects that would let someone say that code is "typical" code and that code isn't "typical" code.

Comment: @igouy Debating you is thoroughly unpleasant. If you can’t stick to facts and need to resort to insults and baseless assumptions to get your point across, maybe take a step back and reflect on why that is. I’ve had enough. I don’t actually need to win your approval.

Comment: @Konrad >>What’s wrong with that?<< You initially said - "I’m all for empiricism" but you seem to think that a threat to the validity can be addressed simply by appeal to "conventional wisdom". If "conventional wisdom" is reliable why bother with experiments? "The results do not always confirm or contradict common expectations, but may be something else entirely, even to the point of being hard to interpret." Plat_Forms

Answer (score 7):

> When I speak of C++ I mean to use lots of OOP and generic programming.

This is probably a bad idea. C++ isn’t primarily an object-oriented language and using it as one “just because” isn’t a good approach. C++ shines much more in generic programming.

Especially if performance is important for you, go with C++, [it’s faster than C while still allowing high abstraction if properly used](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/29109/2366#29136), but don’t use OOP. For a way how C++ can be used much better, have a look at the `<algorithms>` standard header.

Answer (score 1):

No-one can really answer this except you. Do you really need OOP if most of your code will be number crunching?

Answer (score 0):

My vote would be for C as all you need is number crunching and no need for fancy libraries to pass objects around and such. Boost is not that much faster for MPI anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can write efficient code or horrible code in either language.  Your best bet will most likely be to stick with whatever language you are most comfortable with.  Your programming skill will likely give a greater benefit than language choice (assuming you have access to an equally-capable compiler for both languages).

If all else fails, don't forget that you can use both C and C++ in your system.  You can write your number-crunching algorithms in C, build it into a library, and then link that library into a C++ application.

Answer (score 0):

I'd always use C in this kind of app. Just mho.

Comment: This isn't really much of an answer.  Please tell us _why_ you always use C in this kind of app.  The rest of us may learn something.